# Looking for a query

Tags: sql

As you see in the picture below the column ID has numbers which sometimes exists multiple times but each time with a different status from column STATUS. The primary key from the table is ID - STATUS.

I want to query the database so that i only see a list with the ID one time with the highest STATUS from column STATUS.

[image: Picture]

I want to see this result:

```
253794  5
254680  1
257307  1
258562  5
261213  5
261219  5
261220  5
.....
```

How can i extend the query below to obtain the result i need?

```
select *
from STATUSTABLE
where ID in (253794,253794,254680,257307,258562,258562,261213,261213,261219,261219,261220,261220,261222,261222,261223,261223,263544,263544,263544,263544,264804,264804,264823,264823,265616,265616,266233,266233) 
order by ID;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @snorkel , I believe the answer from Gordon is exactly what you need. I just want to point out to you that there is no need to put duplicate ID's inside of the brackets.
Also, if you want to se highest status of all ID's you can remove the entire WHERE clause from the query Gordon wrote.

Comment: Thank you indeed it is not necessary i see to list the duplicate IDs in the where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by`:

```
select id, max(status) as max_status
from STATUSTABLE
where ID in (253794,253794,254680,257307,258562,258562,261213,261213,261219,261219,261220,261220,261222,261222,261223,261223,263544,263544,263544,263544,264804,264804,264823,264823,265616,265616,266233,266233) 
group by id
order by ID;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon this is exactly what i need. I am going to learn more about the group by statement